# How to attach block to page provided by logintoboggan

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have the logintoboggan module installed. By default, Anonymous users will be presented with a login form along with an access denied message when they try to access a page which they do not have the permissions to. Please, how can i attach a block to this page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to redirect users to login when access is denied.

another may be to create your own Access Denied page, and then attach a login block to that URL.

To create your own Access Denied page, first create the page as you would with any other content,  then navigate to: /admin/config/system/site-information

Comment: Thank you. Maybe my question now would be: how do i create my own Access Denied page?

Comment: @seyi edited to answer that .. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with LoginToboggan 7x.-1.4:

1. Visit /admin/config/system/logintoboggan and make sure that "Present login form on access denied (403)" is enabled.
2. Visit /admin/config/system/site-information and confirm that toboggan/denied is the Default 403 page.
3. Create your block at /admin/structure/block/add.
4. Under Visibility settings, specify that the block only appear at toboggan/denied.